# Without integration, explain the following equation

Tags: calculus

$\frac 12 \int_{0}^{1} x^4(1-x)^4 dx\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} x^4(1-x)^4dx$

This is my homework assignment whereby I have no idea of how should i get started. Could i have some hint on this question??

Comment: Hint: if $0 \leq x \leq 1$, then $1/2 \leq 1/(1+x^2) \leq 1$. Now look at the areas that these integrals represent.

Comment: hmm... I still don't get it, @OldJohn

Answer (score 6):

(**) I hope you know that $\,f(x)\geq 0\,\,\,\,\forall\,x\in [a,b]\Longrightarrow \int_a^bf(x)\,dx\geq 0\,$... If you don't then proving this by means of Riemann sums is really easy.

Well, taking now $\,[0,1]\,$, we have that

$$\frac{1}{2}\,x^4(1-x)^4\leq \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}\leq x^4(1-x)^4$$

and now apply (**) to each inequality above

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $x\in[0,1]$
$$\frac12\le\frac1{1+x^2}\le1$$
Multiply by $x^4(1-x)^4$ and integrate over $[0,1]$.

Comment: I see that this is already given in a comment by OldJohn.

Comment: ahhh. im getting what is @OldJohn was trying to say. Thanks